# Ctrl + Right and Right send same Sequence in Putty > Screen > Vim

Tags: vim, gnu-screen, putty

I'm using putty > screen > vim, and screen is sending the same sequence for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> and <kbd>Right</kbd> in application mode for vim.

There is an option to make putty send the cursor mode sequences (disable application cursor keys mode) when in application mode and that works, but when screen is introduced, something isn't right.

How would I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 2):

If I set `term = xterm` in putty, and `term=putty` in `screenrc`, it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

That only *seems* to work.  As I pointed out (later than this question) in [How to enable Control key combinations for GNU screen on putty?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139744/how-to-enable-control-key-combinations-for-gnu-screen-on-putty), the difference when you do not modify `screenrc` is that the terminal description for `screen` sets application mode for the terminal.

However, applications running in screen using this workaround can send escape sequences that screen does not recognize.  Using

```
infocmp putty screen
```

to see, these include

`hpa` (horizontal position absolute),

`vpa` (vertical position absolute),

`indn` (index by a given number of lines), and

`rin` (reverse index by a given number of lines).

Not all applications will misbehave (i.e., those which do little optimization of the screen output will "work"), but ncurses would use those features.

However — since you have the `putty` terminal description available, that implies you have the full ncurses database.  If you set

```
TERM=putty
```

*outside* screen, then screen will use the terminal description [`screen.putty`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-screen_putty), which does what you want.